# link to the current_user via href

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

Currently I have a header that links the user to his profile through this:

```
<li><%= link_to '<i class="icon-picture"></i> My Profile'.html_safe, current_user %></li>
```

I would like to be able to link the current user to his profile by doing something like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="<%= current_user %>">
    <div><%= image_tag current_user.avatar (:small) %></div>
    &nbsp; <strong>Surge Pedroza</strong><br/>
    &nbsp; view my profile page
  </a>
</li>
```

But I do not know how to do it through an `<a href="...">`. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a better way to accomplish what you want:

```
<%= link_to current_user do %>
  <div><%= image_tag current_user.avatar(:small) %></div>
  &nbsp; <strong><%= current_user.full_name %></strong><br/>
  &nbsp; view my profile page
<% end %>
```

`link_to .. do` is useful for the exact situation you are describing. Check the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it :)

```
<a href="<%= current_user.id %>">
```